# Not knowing a whole unicode character python

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, python-unicode

I have a variable in which Unicode characters are typed with string

```
print(x)
# output -> '\u062f\u0631 \u0627\u0628\u0644'

print(type(x))
# output -> <class 'str'>
```

how can i convert x in utf8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')` for doubled *Reverse Solidi*, see [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)

```
x= '\\u062f\\u0631 \\u0627\\u0628\\u0644'
print(x, '->', x.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape'))
```

> ```
> \u062f\u0631 \u0627\u0628\u0644 -> در ابل
> ```

Comment: `x.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')` is sufficient.  There's nothing to escape in the original string.

Comment: @MarkTolonen you are right (for this particular string). However, your solution fails if `x` contains a non-ascii character, e.g. `x= '"در ابل"  is the same as "\\u062f\\u0631 \\u0627\\u0628\\u0644"'`. So I'm on safer side…

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: surrogates not allowed ..................
its not working :(

Comment: @mehdinora surrogates are Unicode range from `U+D800` to `U+DFFF`. I can't see any such codepoint(s) in your or my [mcve].