# How can I remove the backslash escape for a string to be used in unicodedata.normalize()?

Tags: python, string, unicode, hex, ascii

### Problem formulation/example

Consider the latin character `á`, which can be represented as

- `\xe1` in hex
- `\u00e1` in 16-bit hex
- `\U000000e1` in 32-bit hex

In the following code block, I'm decomposing the latin-1 character into an equivalent character with the accent removed (i.e. from `á` to `a`):

```
import unicodedata

decomposed = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', '\xe1') 
encoded = decomposed.encode("utf-8")
letter = chr(list(encoded)[0]) 

print(letter)
```

(Any of the three bullet-pointed formats could have been used in the second argument of `unicodedata.normalize()`.)

#### My issue

My issue is in trying to generalise this, whereby the second argument to `normalize()` is to be an assigned variable.

I'm struggling to do this without explicitly entering the string into the formula because of the escaped backslash.

#### Example attempt

```
latin = "á"
a = ascii(latin) # print(a) gives '\xe1'
decomposed = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', a)  
encoded = decomposed.encode("utf-8")
letter = chr(list(encoded)[0])
```

This won't work because the argument `a` is interpreted as `'\\xe1'` instead of `'\xe1'`.

Other attempts to get the hex representation and construct a string by concatenating `\x` to it won't work either, for the same reason.

Comment: The backslash escape isn't in the string. It's just how the character is represented when you type a literal in the program, and how the `repr()` function shows it. So there's nothing to remove.

Comment: @Barmar ye that makes sense because if I do a[0] I would just get ‘\’. I’m struggling to see why the function interprets the two differently when the backslash escape isn’t actually in the string.

Comment: `'\xe1' == 'á'`.  It's just a way to type a single character with an escape code.  `ascii('á')` generates the 4-character string `'\\xe1'` where `'\\'` is an escape code for a single, literal backslash.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen makes sense. So it comes down to the fact that `ascii('á') != '\xe1'`, so it's simply an invalid representation of `'á'` for use in this function. Any idea on how I can obtain the hex (or preferably 32-bit hex) representation of arbitrary unicode characters that can be used in this function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: @JosefZ I'm trying to solve that exact problem myself so I'm reluctant to visit that link... It's just an educational exercise for me

Comment: The function takes a character. Just pass the character. You don’t need the hex code.  If you have the hex code, `chr()` will return the character

Comment: So [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69650346/3439404)  is what you need… We all are learning from existing common solutions rather than [reinventing the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel)…