# Convert code to symbol python encode decode

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, encode

I have the following string from a txt file

```
07082022    23  15.8   79  1018.9  200    4     PRESIDENCIA ROQUE SAENZ PE\xd1A AERO                                                 \r\n                                                                                                    \r\n07082022     6    .8   85  1033.8   90    9     PUERTO DESEADO AERO
```

I am trying to decode it to get :

```
07082022    23  15.8   79  1018.9  200    4     PRESIDENCIA ROQUE SAENZ PEÑA AERO                                                 \r\n                                                                                                    \r\n07082022     6    .8   85  1033.8   90    9     PUERTO DESEADO AERO
```

I am using `(response.content).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')`
but not found

Comment: What string do you get from `response.text`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not knowing a whole unicode character python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69638558/not-knowing-a-whole-unicode-character-python)

Comment: some servers may use different encoding - ie, `ISO-8859-1` (long time ago very popular on Windows servers) but `response.text` should gives you text already decoded (it checks if server sends information about encoding or it uses `chardet` to detect encoding and uses it to decode `response.content`). I most situations it gives correct text.

Comment: BTW: code `b'\xd1'.decode('iso-8859-1')` gives me `Ñ` - so you would have to use `iso-8859-1` (or `latin1`) instead of `utf-8`

Comment: BTW: there is `response.encoding` which shows what encoding may use page.